# JavaScript: escape vs. unescape

Tags: javascript

I saw some sites were using the JavaScript escape() and unescape() functions interchangeably.

Some used:

```
document.write('<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="..."/>');
```

whereas, this was also pretty common (note: they first "escape" the string, then "unescape" it):

```
document.write(unescape('%3Cimg%20height%3D%221%22%20width%3D%221%22%20style%3D%22border-style%3Anone%3B%22%20alt%3D%22%22%20src%3D%22...%22/%3E'));
```

The latter seems to achieve the same as the former, only using a longer way. Any differences in these two methods?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear in this example.  But you can not have inline scripts containing `<script>` or `</script>` inside of a string, or the browser will try and process it like a script tag.

Escaping and unescaping html avoids this problem.  A better solution is to put the script in a separate file from the html document.

Comment: One common use case is to call a different script / pixel depending upon a certain condition.

For example:
if (condition A) { /* Call script #1 */ }
else { /* Call script #2*/ }

Answer (score 0):

For xhtml compliance you cannot have any HTML tag (`<div></div>` or `<img />`) inside a script block so either you use unescape or concatenation `'<' + 'div...'` or you add `//<![CDATA[  ...   //]]>` inside the script block to pass validation.

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks and similar quotes to the JavaScript's break the parser.

```
var test = "This "string", for example.";
```

Backslash escapes are built-in, so this works:

```
var test = "This \"string\", for example.";
```

But then you'd have to find a function to escape ", ', \n, \r, and from the other answers, < and > as well.

escape() already encodes strings to remove most non-alphanumeric characters, and unescape() undoes escape().

```
escape("It's > 20% less complicated this way.")
```

"It%27s%20%3E%2020%25%20less%20complicated%20this%20way."

If the escaped spaces bother you, try:

```
escape("It's > 20% less complicated this way.").replace(/%20/g, " ")
```

"It%27s %3E 20%25 less complicated this way."